# How do I get the display id of a view in Drupal 6?

Tags: views, 6

I'm trying to use the [views_data_export](http://drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module to get the content of a Drupal 6 view in xml format. On the module's page, it says to use this command:

```
drush views-data-export [view-name] [display-id] [output-file]
```

I can figure out the view name well enough, but how do I get the display id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the view, then hover over the tab link for your display.  Look at the URL.  It will look something like:

http://thesite.com/admin/build/views/edit/the_view_name#views-tab-the_display_id

You should be able to use "the_view_name" and "the_display_id" in the drush command.

Answer (score 2):

If you go and look/edit a view, the display-id is the "Machine Name" listed when you click on any of the displays.  It looks like 'page_#' or 'block_#' by default plus you also have the 'default' display.  They can be anything, though, if you edit them.

ADDITION per @MPD.  This is what I see here on D6 with Views 3, so I guess it doesn't exist with Views 2 (which I've not used in ages)

[image]

and the Machine Name: `page` in the Basic Settings box is telling me this display_id is `page` in View `archive`

Comment: Is this a Views 3 thing?  Since the question was tagged for Drupal 6, I assumed this was Views 2 and I have never seen that option before.

Comment: Thanks for that screenshot.  I have never tried Views 3 on Drupal 6.