# 500 Internal Server Error Services REST JSON Content

Tags: services, 8

I am retrieving JSON from my Drupal Site to show content on an external Device. I am using Drupanium/REST/Services to do so.

Now the problem is weird.

When I try to access this URL, it works fine:-

> .../api/rest/views/region.json

But when I try to run this URL, it gives me a big, shiny and horrendous Internal Server Error (500)

> .../api/rest/views/content.json

I am using Fields in the region.json and Content in content.json within views. I am also attaching a screenshot for both corresponding views, as it might help.

**Region View**
[image: http://i45.tinypic.com/34he9er.png]

**Content View**
[image: http://i48.tinypic.com/f12lx.png]

P.S. Content.json just have to load all of the articles, whereas regions just show the region field.

Do you have any idea what might be wrong.

Comment: So I've been trying to find possible fixes and found out that there is something in the Articles that is creating problem.

As an example I randomly unpublished 4 of the articles and showed only them through View.

It then worked fine.

The problem now is that there are 100 of articles and I'd have to find the exact problem/character or something which creates this problem.

Alternatively, may be a script to ignore it.

Thanks a lot for any feedback.

Comment: My Bad, it's the number of posts. Any number of posts greater than 39 create this error. I don't know how and where to set it ... Any idea?

Comment: For the views services. You must give the display_id for them. Your url should be like that : ../api/rest/views/content.json?display_id=blahblah. To determine the display_id of views you can check from link :  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41820/how-do-i-get-the-display-id-of-a-view-in-drupal-6

Comment: thank you for your assistance. I update it as :- http://myurl.com/csi/api/rest/views/content.json?display_id=page, but still unfortunately, it didn't make any difference. Any other suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: @StephaneSaussier Are you using [Services 3.x](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module?  You don't need to use `.json` extension in your path, so the correct one is `http://myurl.com/csi/api/rest/views/content?display_id=page`