# Including a view in a content type

Tags: views, 6

I have the panels module installed. So I have two types of pages:

1. Under the *Create content/Page*, the basic content type
2. Under *Site Building/Pages/Add Custom Page*, the page with panels

So, I've used the Panel pages all over the place and everything is easy; however, for a particular project, I have some content-types that were based off the basic Page (example 1 above).

I need to figure out how to add a view to that kind of page. There is a lot of HTML with jQuery setup to allow for a custom tab system on one page: Click on a tab and via show/hide the appropriate content shows up and adds a hash tag to the url for deep linking.

I'm guessing I will select PHP code for the input format, but I haven't found the right snippet to include a particular View within all the HTML code that is already there.

I tried to just use `<?php print $content; ?>` within the div for the last tab of content to see if I could get something to render but it didn't show anything so perhaps this isn't the right way anyway?

#### Some notes

My view has four displays and I need to call the one "ISO 14001 docs" but, the view has an argument of "(Document) Content: Link" so that is probably why I have not been successful.

I've tried the following code, but I'm not getting anything and I'm not sure how to add that type of argument in this kind of call.

```
$viewName = 'sc_file_view';
print views_embed_view($viewName);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Views Reference](https://drupal.org/project/viewreference) module that will give you a cck to choose from selected views. This will use with each type of content.

For a same view in all content of content type you will need to create a template file `node--type.tpl.php` and paste your code to include the view.

Answer (score 0):

To embed a view with PHP use the following:

```
$viewName = 'sc_file_view';
$displayId = 'block_3';
$viewArg = 1; // Your view argument goes here
print views_embed_view( $viewName, $displayId, $viewArg );
```

The display ID is usually something like 'page_#' or 'block_#', it would not be named "ISO 14001 docs". You can find your $displayId by reading this link: [How do I get the display id of a view in Drupal 6?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41820/how-do-i-get-the-display-id-of-a-view-in-drupal-6)

Comment: Hmm, doesn't work for me. However, I just took out the $viewArg as my argument isn't a number; it's "Document: Content Link" and has the default "Node ID from URL" checked. Is that value needed to get output with this snippet?